# Joomla 3.1.5 & extplorer 2.1.3 install issues

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I get the following errors when installing with Joomla! version, 3.1.5.  I am not sure if this is a compatibility issue or a software bug.  Has anyone else seen this or no how I can get around this?

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method ext_Lang::detect_lang() should not be called statically in D:\Coral\UniServer\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_extplorer\include\init.php on line 103

Strict Standards: Non-static method ext_Result::init() should not be called statically in D:\Coral\UniServer\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_extplorer\admin.extplorer.php on line 97

Strict Standards: Non-static method ext_Result::empty_errors() should not be called statically in D:\Coral\UniServer\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_extplorer\include\result.class.php on line 40

Strict Standards: Non-static method ext_Result::empty_messages() should not be called statically in D:\Coral\UniServer\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_extplorer\include\result.class.php on line 41

Strict Standards: Declaration of ext_List::execAction() should be compatible with ext_Action::execAction($dir, $item) in D:\Coral\UniServer\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_extplorer\include\list.php on line 387

Back to Joomla! eXtplorer Logo Current mode: extplorer [Logout]. You could switch to ftp mode.

Strict Standards: Non-static method extHTML::loadExtJS() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in D:\Coral\UniServer\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_extplorer\include\list.php on line 374
```

Comment: What version of Apache and more importantly PHP are you using

Comment: Apache 2.4.6 VC10 - OpenSSl 1_0_1e
MySQL 5.5.32-community
PHP 5.4.17 OpenSSL 1_0_1e Intl 50
phpMyAdmin 4.0.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think Joomla is ready for PHP5.4 yet.

You could try checking your php.ini value for `error_reporting` and add `| ~E_STRICT` to it to stop it reporting these probelms

Comment: I add your change and stopped and started the server and I still get the same errors  the line looks like this==error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT

Comment: As Far as PHP%.4 goes this seem to be the only extension I am having problems getting to work.

Comment: Joomla 3.x works fine with PHP 5.4, however it's best that strict error reporting is turned off

Answer (score 0):

You should turn strict error reporting off in your **php.ini**

Find the following:

```
error_reporting = ...
```

and change to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

Comment: @SteveM - go to your Global Configuration and ensure that error reporting is on *Standard* and not *Development*

Comment: Global Configuration in what?  I don't see that in PHP.ini

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear. The Global Configuration is in the Joomla backend ;)

Comment: In Joomla under the server settings, Error Reporting is set to "System Default"

Comment: Otherwise do you know of a way to add FTP to Joomla?  I have a page that Works, but part of it is ASP.

Comment: Have we come to an impasse?

Comment: @SteveM - sorry I didn't seem to get the notification for your first comment. For an FTP on Joomla, you could use [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/2630)

Comment: LOL, that's what I am trying to use and it is giving me these errors.

Comment: haha oh god, I'm absolutely failing at life today. Try [MijoFTP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/22425). It's definitely because of the fact you're using PHP 5.4.

Comment: I had looked at that but didn't see anything for FTP it says it can handle large files without FTP.

Comment: hmm, well it's definitely due to the fact that you on PHP 5.4 and the error reporting

Comment: I spoke with the people at  MijoFTP and they don't have a FTP extension, I suggested they take FTP out of the name of that program.

Comment: is there a way to tell which PHP.INI file is in use from the browser?

Comment: unfortunately not. there's usually only be 1 *php.ini* file being used unless the user has created a new one.

Answer (score 0):

## 1st Method

in your php code use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);`

## 2nd Method

in your php.ini, with change `error_reporting = E_ALL`  to `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT`. Please make sure to restart Apache server after the changes are made to php.ini